# Disable IntelliJ / RubyMine Spellchecking for Filenames?

Tags: intellij-idea

I may be way off base here, but RubyMine appears to be spellchecking my filenames:

[image: RubyMine / IntelliJ file listing]

Problem is, I have spellchecking turned off.

This occurs for some directory names as well, including simple names like "views".

How do I disable this?

Comment: It's not spellchecking, such underline indicates that there are errors inside this file. Open the file and check the right gutter for the error marks to see what's the problem, disable the corresponding inspections if they do not apply for your use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not spellchecking, such underline indicates that there are errors inside this file.